# mmenu menu system not working within .Net form tag

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, mmenu

am currently looking to implement the mobile menu system **mmenu** (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) into our Asp.Net site.

Works great on an HTML page and also in the Master page, so long as it's outside the form tag.  When I put it within the form tag it no longer works.

Here is the HTML for the menu:

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page.html">The page</a></li>
        <li><a href="mainmenu.html">The mainmenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="submenus.html">Submenus</a></li>
        <li><a href="labels.html">Labels</a></li>
        <li><a href="counters.html">Counters</a></li
        <li><a href="selected.html">Selected item</a></li>
        <li><a href="openmenu.html">Open the menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="closemenu.html">Close the menu</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This runs it fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('nav#menu').mmenu({
            zposition: "next",
            position: "top"
        });
    });
</script>
```

But then if I put it within the form tag (form id="MainForm" runat="server") I get a jquery error.  Needs to be within as some menu items will come from the database.

Cheers
Simon

Comment: What is the error? Are you accounting for the fact that asp.net changes element `id`s when they are marked as `runat="server"`?

Answer (score 5):

Mmenu does two things when it is initialized. First, it wraps the innerHTML of the `<body>` with a `<div class="mmenu-page">` container, and then it cuts out the `<nav>` for the menus and moves those between the `<body>` and new page container in the DOM.

For whatever reason, it treats the ASP.Net wrapping `<form>` tag like the `<body>` tag, but only if it appears as the first child of the `<body>`. When this is the case, it inserts it's wrapping `<div>` immediately following the closing `<form>` tag.

If you wrap your ASP.Net `<form>` tag with an empty `<div>`, mmenu will be able to target it's `<div class="mmenu-page">` correctly and everything magically works.

You'll want your code aspx page to look like this:

```
<body>
 <div>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
   ...
   <nav> ...mobile menu... </nav>
  </form>
 </div>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The empty div wrapping body didn't work for me.  I found a post on GitHub that worked great:

```
$('#search-copy').mmenu({
  // options
}, {
  // config
  offCanvas: {
      menuWrapperSelector: "#aspnetForm",
      pageNodetype: "form",
      pageSelector: "body > form"
  }
});
```

Here's the original post:

https://github.com/FrDH/jQuery.mmenu/issues/426

You may need to play around with your selectors.  I ended up using an ID for pageSelector and a generic selector for menuWrapperSelector.

With mmenu, I found that there were a lot of hidden configuration and options settings.  Some were in the mmenu docs, some were in the OffCanvas docs.  Seems like the configuration/options settings will do just about anything you want without having to write a lot of custom CSS.