# MMENU - $page.offset undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, mmenu

I'm developing some mobile navigation using http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/ but I keep getting the following error in Firebug

```
TypeError: $page.offset(...) is undefined
```

It's referring to line 1131 in jquery.mmenu.js which is the following code snippet.

```
.data( _d.offetLeft, $page.offset().left );
```

The website is being developed in ASP.NET so I think the problem might be because ASP.NET pages are wrapped in "form" tags and the plugin is only taking into consideration body and html tags???

The reason I think this is because I've got the menu working pefectly with no problems in a test I did with a normal HTML page.

Any ideas on how to fix it???? I really want to use the plugin and the project has to be developed in ASP.NET.

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wasn't getting this exact JavaScript error, I did run into an issue where mmenu wouldn't properly wrap the content of the page for it's slide transition.

Take a look at this other question and see if my answer over there helps you out: [mmenu not working within .Net form tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382424/mmenu-menu-system-not-working-within-net-form-tag/19556896#19556896)

Comment: This worked a treat. I was using a semi fix that involved adding the line of code: $body = $('form'); in jquery.menu.js on line 764 but yours is much better! Cheers bud!